# How can I add a resource file in Grails application?

Tags: java, grails, resources

I'm using Grails 2.4.3 and for my project, I need to load a resource file from a .java in /src/java/com/company/MyClass.java

I tried the following code :

```
 ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("myfile.txt")
```

I tried to put the file everywhere in the project but it doesn't seem to find it.

It worked when I put the file in target/classes during the compilation. But it's not viable (I can't do this at every deployment)

How can I declare resources in a grails app to use in Java code ?

Comment: What kind of file is it and what do you want to do with it? Normally web resources are stored under '/web-app'

Comment: It's just a file which contains some data. it's not a web resource. In Maven we can declare resources folder in pom.xml. How can I do that with Grails or Java ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no dedicated resource directory for classpath resources, but resources are included from the source directories.

You can for instance place your resources in (preferably a sub-directory of) `grails-app/conf` or `src/java`.

You might run into problems loading them with the system class-loader (who knows what class loader magic is happening in the web application), but the following works fine for me:

```
def myFileContents = getClass().getResource('/mydir/myfile.txt').text
```

One final note, if the file is a java or groovy file, and you don't want it to compile (I ran into this case some time ago), then you have the option to include it directly in the correct web application directory: `web-app/WEB-INF/classes/mydir/myfile.groovy`

Comment: In what scenario would one want to include a Java or Groovy file without compiling it?

Comment: @Dónal: There are a few scenarios. In my case it was a configuration file that I read with ConfigSlurper. Could also be a script or template. I have also encountered an instance where java example code should be included as resources.